# Share canvas image on android

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, share

Hello so I write a small game where in the end you can share your result. The result is written on an image using canvas. The problem is when sharing i get the error "Error, could not locate the file". The error is seen on screen only and not reflected in logcat. I've already spent countless hours trying to solve it, but nothing seems to work. I get no errors what so ever but the file still appears to be impossible to share. Does anyone has a suggestion on why it does not work?

Quick recap: Load bitmap, make it a canvas, paint it, check for permissions to save, save it, get the URI of the saved file, use the URI inside of the share intent. I really don't see what is missing.

The canvas painting part was tested separately and I was able to share the bitmap to Facebook using fb library. Unfortunately android native share does not allow to share bitmaps without saving them.

In manifest I have WRITE and READ permissions for both internal and external storage. I would really appreciate any help.

Share button on click listener:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.Myimage); 
                mutableBitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);
                Paint paint = new Paint();
                paint.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD));
                paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                paint.setTextSize(170);

                int top_margin = 1000;
                int left_margin = 1700;

                canvas.drawText("You got a ton of points", left_margin, top_margin, paint);

ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(test_process.this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1);
```

Permission result:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                sharethis(mutableBitmap);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(test_process.this, "Permission denied to read your External storage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Share method:

```
public void sharethis(Bitmap bitmap){

    File file_path = getFilesDir();

    File file = new File(file_path, "resultImg.jpg");
    FileOutputStream fOut;
    try {
        fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("file saving problem", String.valueOf(e));
    }

    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Uri uriContent = getImageContentUri(this, file);

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("image/jpeg");
    Log.i("Uri", String.valueOf(uri));
    Log.i("UriContent", String.valueOf(uriContent));
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriContent);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Cover Image"));
}
```

And URI convertor:

```
public static Uri getImageContentUri(Context context, File imageFile) {
    String filePath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID },
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + "=? ",
            new String[] { filePath }, null);

    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int id = cursor.getInt(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID));
        Uri baseUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/images/media");
        return Uri.withAppendedPath(baseUri, "" + id);
    } else {
        if (imageFile.exists()) {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, filePath);
            return context.getContentResolver().insert(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getImageContentUri()` is not going to work. Your file is on [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html); third-party apps, including the `MediaStore`, have no access to it.

Get rid of `getImageContentUri()`. [Set up `FileProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) to serve files from `getFilesDir()`. Then, use `FileProvider.getUriForFile()` to get a `Uri` that you can use in your `ACTION_SEND` `Intent`.

Also:

- You will need to add `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` to the `ACTION_SEND` `Intent`
- You do not need `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` for any of this

Comment: instead of `FileProvider` (and storing the `Bitmap` in the physical file) did you try to setup a `ContentProvider` and override `openFile` method?

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. It works. Just if anyone will be looking into this solution, the filepath that I used is as follows: <files-path name="files" path="."/> . Took me some time to figure it out.